# Second times fetched data (with the same method) return null

Tags: ios, core-data, fetch

I fetched the data from core data, first time is return correct result.
I want to fetch it again for update the fetch offset, I fetched with the same method but it return null

this is my code

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = delegate.managedObjectContext;

ChatInfo *chat = [ChatInfo getInstance];

fetchRequest.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"AudioHistory" inManagedObjectContext:context];



// fectch max date first
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(uploadedby == %@ && sentto == %@) || (uploadedby == %@ && sentto == %@)", chat.userid, chat.friendid, chat.friendid, chat.userid];

fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"ms_createdAt" ascending:YES]];

NSFetchedResultsController *firstFetchedResult =
[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                    managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                               cacheName:nil];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

if (objects.count >= 10) {

    [fetchRequest setFetchOffset:objects.count-10];
}

//self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
self.fetchedResultsController = firstFetchedResult;

_fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

return _fetchedResultsController;
```

}

what I do wrong?

Comment: Called how? Why are you using an offset?

Comment: @Wain When my tableview scroll to top I want to load more ( not sure what it call, paging?) like chat view in LINE. This is why I want to change an offset. I called by used this code [self fetchedResultController];

Answer (score 0):

You have some code when creating the FRC to check if it actually needs to be done:

```
if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

so, if it already exists it will just be returned. So the second time you request the FRC a new fetch won't be made and no changes to the fetch request will be made.

If you need them to be then you need to destroy the existing FRC (`self.fetchedResultsController = nil;`) or have a separate methods which changes the fetch request.

Remember that when you change the fetch request you explicitly have to call `performFetch` on the FRC or the change will be ignored.

From your comment you want to scroll to load more, that shouldn't be done using the FRC. The FRC should just be observing the whole data set in Core Data. If you want to load more you should detect the request (button, pull, scroll, whatever) and trigger a new download / object creating in Core Data. The FRC will see that change and call its delegate methods as appropriate.

Comment: I detected by used this code

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if ([scrollView contentOffset].y == 0) {
        NSLog(@"scrolled to top");
        NSLog(@"%ld", (long)pageSize);
        [[self headerActivityIndicator] startAnimating];
        [self performSelector:@selector(stopAnimatingHeader) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
    }
    
    
}

Is this the good way to load more data?  I'll learn about it more. Thanks mate!

Comment: That looks like a fine way to trigger the check if there is more to load and to start the load.